# Using a lamba in vb.net to get DataTables difference

Tags: vb.net, lambda

Using VB.NET and lambda, I am trying to retrieve all the records in the first DataTable (table01) that are not in the second DataTable (table02).  But cannot get this to work:

```
Dim newList = table01.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) Not table02.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x1) x1.Field("CustomerNumber") = x.Field("CustomerNumber") AndAlso x1.Field("CustomerId") = x.Field("CustomerId") AndAlso x1.Field("DetailID") = x.Field("DetailID")))
```

The error is :

"Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments"

Not sure what I am missing but it does not like the Where clause. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't say why you "cannot get this to work", but the [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method has a generic parameter that you are not supplying - e.g. `x.Field(Of Integer)("CustomerId")` (substituting the appropriate type).

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the text.  The error is "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments"